# Ruby - Check URL for specific in-page result

Tags: ruby, url, rubygems

I am a total newbie and worked out a ruby file that allows to check websites if they are live or if they return a 404 error. It looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

urls = %w(
https://www.nytimes.com/2017/11/30/world/americas/argeeentine-navy-gives-up-hope-of-finding-submarine-crew-alive.html
)

require "open-uri"
require "nokogiri"

missing = []
urls.each do |url|
  begin
    open(url).read.include?("Argentina")
  rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
    if e.message == "404 Not Found"
      missing << url
      puts "#{url} is missing!"
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I want to change the script and check a long list of website URLs that do not give a 404 message but a "regular" website that says "this content is currently not available".

Thus, my question is: How do I have to change the code above in order to have result that indicates those URLs from the list that give out that message  "this content is currently not available" ?

Thanks in advance for any help - also regarding how stupid my question might be for an experienced coder!

Much apprecitated!
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and simple implementation:

```
open(url).read.include?("this content is currently not available")
```

As your logic for detecting "non-resolving" web pages grows, you may wish to start abstracting these checks into other methods/classes.

Comment: Hi Tom Lord,

thx for your prompt response!

I tried your implementation - but it doesn't work; only if i deliberately type in a false URL. Which is due because of line 15 still checking the rescue OpenURI::HTTPError I guess ?

I made the changes in the original code above visible for you

Comment: @TomTe You'll still need to somehow store the value in your array! Below, you used `missing << url`. The code I provided could, for example, be used in a simple `if` statement.